# Batch file / script in Windows to delete Parent folder and all content if a folder in it has word Codec

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have some downloading directories in which temporarily houses downloaded files.

Sometimes these automatically download parent folders that have a fake video file as well as a folder with the name of "Codec'.

Basically what I want to achieve is to delete the entire PARENT folder and all of its content (both files and sub-directories) if there is a folder anywhere with the name 'Codec'.  Not just delete the Codec folder.

Kind of a method of cleaning up the main folder of these fake and useless ones.

Any help would be appreciated :).

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: haven't tried, i am clueless with scripting of any kind, googling was confusing as well lol, I am looking for advice

Answer (score 0):

You could use PowerShell.  Maybe something like this..

Remove the -Confirm if you dont want to verify each deletion.

```
$searchDirectory = "C:\Temp\Download"

$search = Get-ChildItem -Directory -Path $searchDirectory -Filter Codec* -Recurse

foreach($folder in $search){
    Remove-Item $folder.FullName -Recurse -Confirm
}
```